# Python как постоянно выводить текст/выполнять действия

Tags: python

Пусть мне необходимо, чтобы основная часть кода выполнялась постоянно

```
while 1==1:
    print (int(input ('square: '))**2)
```

Но при этом код также выводил на экран текст/делал какое-то действие каждые 3 секунды

Как это осуществить?

Пример выводимого результата:

```
>>>square:2
>>>4
>>>square:
>>>do_something
>>>square:
>>>do_something #"do_something" должно выводиться каждые 3 секунды
>>>square:6
>>>36
>>>square:
>>>do_something
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: вам просто нужна задержка между итерациями цикла в 3 секунды? или работать не прирывно, а сообщение раз 3 секунды печатать?

Comment: Цикл должен работать как обычно, но параллельно должен выводиться текст

Comment: Почитайте про модуль [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process).

Comment: @МихаилМуругов он тут совершенно ни к чему

Comment: В каждой (или почти каждой) итерации проверять текущее время, если с момента последней печати прошло 3 секунды или больше, то печатать

Comment: я все еще не понимаю, что не так с моим ответом. В какой ситуации он не работает? просто замените мое `text` на `do_something` и оно будет выводиться раз в 3 секунды

Comment: Если пользователь не будет вводить значение, то "do_something" никогда не выведется

Comment: Ну тогда вам в многопоточку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как я понял, вам необходимо *параллельно* при работе главной программы ещё что-то выводить. В таком случае решение:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process
import time

def printer():
    while True:
        print("Working...")
        time.sleep(3)

def main():
    while True:
        print (int(input ('square: '))**2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    subproc = Process(target=printer)
    subproc.start()
    main()
```

Обратите внимание, что для использования `multiprocessing.Process` конструкция `if __name__ == "__main__":` обязательна. Если же вам необходимо выводить значение какой-то переменной, которая меняется со временем в главной программе, то необходимо почитать [обмен объектами между процессами](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

Comment: А чем вам threading не угодил?

Comment: AttributeError: __exit__ что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте ещё раз. Я привёл код с использованием конструкции `with ... as ...` предварительно не попробовав сам с ней. Сейчас всё должно работать.

Comment: @andreymal Личным опытом и статьямим, где сравниваются `threading` и `multiprocessing`. Главным критерием к неуважению `threading` для меня является GIL.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, хоть у ТС и задача в вакууме, но из того, что есть - ввод/вывод. Потоков тут будет достаточно.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов как именно GIL мешает решить задачу, описанную в данном вопросе?

Comment: @mkkik Соглашусь. Порождать ещё один процесс ради одного вывода это накладно, но я для себя забраковал модуль `threading` и стараюсь его избегать (понимаю, что это глупо, но вот так).

Comment: @andreymal Я не говорил, что GIL мешает решить данную задачу :) Я указал, что GIL сугубо для _меня_ является главной причиной не использовать потоки. В конце концов, вы сами можете привести решение задачи с использованием потоков, пусть ТС выбирает, что для него лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Простой способ просто печатать раз в 3 секунды

```
import time
last_time = time.time() # вернет unixtime, то есть секунды
interval = 3
while True:
#     ... тут ваш основной код
# ...

# дальше код того, что выводится раз в 3 секунды
    current_time = round(time.time()) 
    if current_time > last_time + interval:
        print ("do_something")
        last_time = current_time
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, что мне нужно. Если я в основной части(которая в начале цикла) буду запрашивать действия от пользователя (например,через input), то 'text' выведется только после этого

Comment: @Некто это в точности соответствует текущей формулировке вопроса. Уточните текст вопроса значит

Comment: @Некто а в каких случаях оно вам не подходит?

Comment: Я сверху изменил комментарий

Comment: @Некто все еще не понял. Обновите вопрос добавив пример работы программы

Answer (score 0):

Всё-таки да. Меня убедили, что конкретно для этой задачи лучше использовать потоки

```py
from threading import Thread
import time

def printer():
    while True:
        print("Working...")
        time.sleep(3)

def main()
    while True:
        print (int(input ('square: '))**2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #daemon=True чтобы поток завершился вместе с программой
    thread = Thread(target=printer, daemon=True)
    thread.start()
    main()
```